# I Wrote a Custom In-Place Sorting Method for Integer Arrays (Javascript) - Time Complexity? Sorting Method Name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort, in-place

I wrote a simple algorithm for sorting an array of integers in JS. I'd like to know what the Time and Space Complexity is and whether or not this is an efficient algorithm. I couldn't find this sorting method listed elsewhere online (although it seems similar to bubble sort). I realize that JS has a built in sort function but I wrote this for practice. Please let me know what you think:

```
function arraySort(array){
  var i = 0;

  //helper function to sort backwards
  function leftSort(j){
    if(array[j] < array[j-1]){
      //swap in place
      temp = array[j]
      array[j] = array[j-1]
      array[j-1] = temp
      if(j-1 > 0){
        //call recursively to swap further left
        leftSort(j-1)
      }
    }
  }

  //sort forwards
  while(i < array.length){
    if(array[i] > array[i+1]){
      //swap in place
      var temp = array[i]
      array[i] = array[i+1]
      array[i+1] = temp
      if(i>0){
        //sort swapped value backwards to the left
        leftSort(i)
      }
    }
    i++
  }

  leftSort(i)

  return array
}
```

Comment: 'a' was supposed to be 'array', fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to essentially be a bubble sort with a peculiar order of execution.

Your algorithm travels the array forth and back (n)*(0.5n) times -> O(n^2). Space complexity is constant, since this is a in-place sort.

Comment: It is different from bidirectional bubble sort. I do not repeatedly traverse the array. I actually only iterate through a single time.

Comment: Right. I took a new look and it seems that your code sort of does backwards bubble sort. Still, the complexity seems to be ~O(n^2).

Comment: @LiamTrampota Don't you iterate the array forward once but walk backwards n times?

Comment: I think worst case I walk backwards (n×(n+1))/2

Comment: @SamiHult is this a slight optimization of bubblesort? I believe in this algo there are fewer redundant comparisons

Comment: Perhaps, still the ~O(n^2) holds and the gain of this is negligible as n grows. (Same is true for the bidirectional bubble sort.)

Comment: I would like to add that like the original bubble sort, these kinds of algorithms mainly serve an educational purpose. As such, they are not unimportant, but they are of little practical value.